# VS Code сокращения и вывод console.log()

Tags: visual-studio-code

подскажите как сменить вывод console.log('*курсор мышки') при сокращенном наборе log + tab.
Я хочу чтобы при наборе log + tab подставлялся console.log(*курсор мышки) // без кавычек '' которые сейчас появляются

Answer (score 1):

1. Откройте vscode, выберите `File-Preferences-User Code Snippet`.
2. Выберите тип javascript и откройте файл javascript.json.
3. Следуйте инструкциям по настройке быстрого доступа:

```json
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "log",
        "body": [
            "console.log($0);",
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    }
```